# "CodeResources file must be a symbolic link"

Tags: iphone

[image]

when I upload Iphone to App store then following bugs is coming.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue with XCode (new submission interface), and all it took was to:

```
delete the build folder
clean, and then
build and archive again.
```